# MongoDB accessing object property returns undefinded

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I am fetching a coach from my mongoDB database. I am using this function to get individual properties from an object.

```js
exports.getCoachingTimeframes = async (id, date) => {
    console.log(id, date);
    const coach = await Coach.findById(id);
    console.log(coach) => object
    console.log(coach.name) => "name"
    console.log(coach.coachingTimeframes) => undefined
    return coach;
};
```

Here is the whole coach object:

```js
{
  _id: 'test-trainer',
  name: 'Test Trainer',
  status: '(Nur zum Testen...)',
  image: 'https://trainingsplan-tennis.web.app/assets/trainer/test-trainer.png',
  coachingTimeframes: { totalBookings: 0 },
  isActive: true,
  index: 100,
  __v: 0
}
```

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Using the ThreeDots Operator in JS you can copy the whole object:

```js
exports.getCoachingTimeframes = async (id, date) => {
    console.log(id, date);
    const coach = await Coach.findById(id);
    const object = { ...coach };
    console.log(object._doc.coachingTimeframes)
    return coach;
};
```

If you log the object you can see that the object is constructed differently than it shows in the console:

```js
{
  '$__': InternalCache {
    activePaths: StateMachine { paths: [Object], states: [Object] },
    skipId: true
  },
  '$isNew': false,
  _doc: {
    _id: 'test-trainer',
    name: 'Test Trainer',
    status: '(Nur zum Testen...)',
    image: 'https://trainingsplan-tennis.web.app/assets/trainer/test-trainer.png',
    coachingTimeframes: { totalBookings: 0 },
    isActive: true,
    index: 100,
    __v: 0
  }
}
```

with this new clone of the object you can access the property with the correct path like this:

```js
    console.log(object._doc.coachingTimeframes)
```

I hoped my answer helped you!